# Get full path of a package situated in source folder from junit

Tags: java, reflection, junit, classloader

I have used below code in my **junit** to get the directory of my package.

```
String pkgname = "com.acn.omi.util";
String relPath = pkgname.replace('.', '/');
URL resource = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(relPath);
```

But this code search for package in **target/test-classes** folder which contain classes from **src/test/java** source folder so it is not able to find the package situated in my source folder(src/main/java).

How can i get the file situated in a package from junit.

My purpose is to load all the classes from that folder and modify their field using reflection.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to fetch the classes location using the below code

```
String pkgname = "com.acn.omi.util";
    String relPath = pkgname.replace('.', '\\');
    String workingDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    String requiredDirectory = workingDirectory + "\\" + "src\\test\\java"
            + relPath;
    URL resource = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(
            requiredDirectory);
```

This will fetch you the complete location to the test classes.

Comment: Coming to think of it, you can better use System.getProperty(“file.separator”) instead of "\\" . File seperators are different in windows/mac.

Comment: i tried with this line String requiredDirectory = workingDirectory + "\\" + "src\\main\\java\\"
            + relPath; but i found the url empty

Comment: According to the documentation of getResource() method <br/> `A URL object for reading the resource, or null if the resource could not be found or the invoker doesn't have adequate privileges to get the resource.` <br/> Please check if the constructed path does really exist.

Comment: Also what you are providing as an argument to the URL is a direcory. Please give a file as an argument to the getResource method.

Comment: I advice you to refer to the below link to be able to load the class files using URL. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html#example

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write like this

```
URL resource = User.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()
```

In my case class "User" is placed in target package, so I've output it tests like this:

```
file:.../target/classes/
```